# how can I run multiple if controller in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am currently working in a heavy load test, I have one login request which access with user and password and basic auth, I have to validate some info from the response and I am using assertions but I need to apply different kind of assert depending on the code response and to be able to do that I am using an if control putting the assertions inside as a child, the problem begins when I try to execute the assertions with an error code response, some how the if controller is not taking the value of the variable I created to store the code response. could some one help me? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put assertion as a direct child of the If Controller. In fact you can, however it will not make any sense as assertions obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) and since there is no any Sampler in the Assertion scope - it will simply not get executed.

I would recommend going for [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) where you have all power of [Groovy SDK](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/) and [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) in order to set up your custom pass/fail criteria. The pseudo code would be something like:

```
if (SampleResult.getResponseCode().equals('200')) {
    //do what you need when response code is 200
    //for example let's check if response contains "foo" line
    if (!SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString().contains('foo')) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Failed to find "foo" line in the response')
    }
}
else if (SampleResult.getResponseCode().equals('300')) {
    //do what you need when response code is 300
}
else if (SampleResult.getResponseCode().equals('400')){
    //do what you need when response code is 400
}
else {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Unexpected response code: ' + SampleResult.getResponseCode())
}
```

References:

- [SampleResult documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- [AssertionResult documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you so much!! @Dimitri T, the way you explained make it easier and cover what I was looking for.